# How to generate memory leak by QString and other implicit sharing data structure of Qt

Tags: c++, qt

QString and many data structure of Qt are implicit sharing

How could I make their memory leak?

Circular dependency would cause memory leak if it is shared_ptr
Would QString and other QString like data structure in Qt memory leak too?
I want to know how to make the memory of QString leak, so I would not fall 
into the trap of it.

After some study, looks like I don't have to worry about circular dependency when
it is QString? Thanks to your reply, now I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Don't you have to do the assignments in the opposite order to create a circular dependency?

Comment: Even if you do, there's no circular dependency here. (Plus Qt uses reference counters, the shared state will get cleaned up once the three objects die.)

Comment: So QString don't have the trap like circular dependency?Is it possible to make QString memory leak?

Comment: It's not possible to make QString leak like that unless there's a bug in the QString implementation - there's no circular dependency introduced by your code, and I don't see how you could make that happen. Your code could leak QStrings like it could leak any other object/resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions of Qt prior to 4 concurrent access to two copies of a QString which shared the same data could cause problems because QString is COW but did not lock the ref count. This was a gotcha. As of version 4 the ref count is handled using atomics which solves the problem. 
You can mangle some Qt containers by putting things in them that can throw in odd places but I can't think of a way that could affect QString. Be warry of exception handling in Qt, the doc's are quite vague which usually means beware ;)

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/exceptionsafety.html

If you run out of memory when running Qt expect the world to end, in that case it's probably doesn't matter if the QString leaked or not.